# AWS Elasticbeanstalk install node and npm in PHP instance type

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a PHP application that uses gulp to build the production files, I'm using elasticbeanstalk to deploy my app to and AWS EC2 instance and I want to install node and npm to run gulp during the deploy, my current configuration is:

01-installPackages.config inside .ebextenstions folder

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
  02installNode:
    command:
      # run this command from /tmp directory
      cwd: /tmp
      # don't run the command if node is already installed (file /usr/bin/node exists)
      test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
      # install from epel repository
      # flag -y for no-interaction installation
      command: 'sudo yum install -y nodejs --enablerepo=epel'
```

the node commands fails but if I ssh in and i run that command node is installed

any idea of what's wrong with my configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @matteo, did you have a solution? You can share?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

The current answer for this is the following:

```
commands:
  01enable_epel:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
  02npm_install:
    command: sudo yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
```

using the extras library documented [in AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library)

Comment: Worked like a charm on Amazon AMI Linux 2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [environment configuration options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages) for this rather than writing a bash file yourself. You can use the packages key to download and install prepackaged applications and components.

This will allow you do something like this:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    nodejs: [] 
    npm: []
```

And the packages you require will be installed.

Note: This has been deprecated in Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I originally tried that but I had some problems with sudo and the execution was even slower than creating a file

Comment: This threw errors telling me those packages weren't available via yum.

Comment: @JamesParker
Same response here. Any Solution?